# connect AWS EC2 postgresql with docker apache superset container

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, apache-superset

I am running postgresql in AWS EC2 ubuntu OS. I have successfully connected to pgAdmin. I have also succesefully run a docker container for apache superset and logged in successfully.

When I try to link superset with a postgresql database using the below:

```
**Database *** testdb
**SQLAlchemy URI ***postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:mypassword@awsUbuntupublicIP:5432/testdb
```

I get the below error
ERROR: Connection failed, please check your connection settings.

Comment: Did you check the Inbound port settings on the EC2 instance Security Group?

Comment: I have opened up the port as PostgreSQL
TCP
5432
0.0.0.0/0